# Networkx to_edgelist() and from_edgelist() give me different graphs for an edgelist generated from one graph

Tags: python, graph, networkx

The following code

```py
import networkx as nx
import numpy as np

# Create a graph

random_graph = nx.erdos_renyi_graph(10, 0.5, seed=2)

G = random_graph

# Get the edge list representation
edge_list = nx.to_edgelist(G)

# Create a new graph from the edge list
new_G = nx.from_edgelist(edge_list)

# Check if the graphs are the same
print("Original Graph Adjacency Matrix:")
print(np.array(nx.adjacency_matrix(G).todense()))


print("New Graph Adjacency Matrix:")
print(np.array(nx.adjacency_matrix(new_G).todense()))


# Print adjacency matrices of the original and reconstructed graphs
original_adj_matrix = np.array(nx.adjacency_matrix(G).todense())
new_adj_matrix = np.array(nx.adjacency_matrix(new_G).todense())

# Compare adjacency matrices with a tolerance for floating-point differences
if np.allclose(original_adj_matrix, new_adj_matrix, atol=1e-8):
    print("The original and reconstructed graphs are the same.")
else:
    print("The original and reconstructed graphs are different.")
```

Produces the following output:

```
Original Graph Adjacency Matrix:
[[0 0 0 1 1 0 0 0 1 0]
 [0 0 0 0 1 1 1 0 0 0]
 [0 0 0 0 1 1 1 1 1 1]
 [1 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 1 1]
 [1 1 1 1 0 1 1 0 0 0]
 [0 1 1 0 1 0 1 0 0 0]
 [0 1 1 0 1 1 0 0 0 0]
 [0 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 1 0]
 [1 0 1 1 0 0 0 1 0 0]
 [0 0 1 1 0 0 0 0 0 0]]
New Graph Adjacency Matrix:
[[0 1 1 1 0 0 0 0 0 0]
 [1 0 1 1 0 0 0 0 0 1]
 [1 1 0 0 1 1 1 1 0 0]
 [1 1 0 0 0 0 0 1 1 0]
 [0 0 1 0 0 1 1 0 0 0]
 [0 0 1 0 1 0 1 1 0 0]
 [0 0 1 0 1 1 0 1 0 0]
 [0 0 1 1 0 1 1 0 1 1]
 [0 0 0 1 0 0 0 1 0 0]
 [0 1 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 0]]
The original and reconstructed graphs are different.
```

Am I doing something wrong?

I was expecting the methods to_edgelist() and from_edgelist() to produce the same graphs, however they are both very different.

On different runs, the original and the new adjacency matrix remain the same, but they don't match.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your issue is due to the non consistent order of the nodes.

As noted in the documentation of [`adjacency_matrix`](https://networkx.org/documentation/stable/reference/generated/networkx.linalg.graphmatrix.adjacency_matrix.html), the `nodelist` parameter controls the order of the rows/columns:

> nodelist
> list, optional
>
> The rows and columns are ordered according to the nodes in nodelist. If nodelist is None, then the ordering is produced by
> G.nodes().

Thus you should use a defined order:

```
nodes = sorted(G)

edge_list = nx.to_edgelist(G, nodelist=nodes)
new_G = nx.from_edgelist(edge_list)

np.array_equal(nx.adjacency_matrix(G, nodelist=nodes).todense(),
               nx.adjacency_matrix(new_G, nodelist=nodes).todense())
# True
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer! Adding 'nodelist=nodes' to adjacency_matrix() worked. However, I did not need to add 'nodelist=nodes' to the to_edgelist() method for it to show the correct response.